# Polygon covered by the intersection of multiple linestrings (PostGIS)

Tags: postgis

I have a set a linestrings, and I would like to know the area covered by the intersection of those lines.

I don't want to merge them though. To make things clearer, here is a diagram of three multiline strings. I want to get the pink polygons.

How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: The intersection of a pair of lines is, at most, a collection of lines and/or points (neither of which have area). So your real task here is making polygons from line segments which touch at more than one point.

Comment: do not forget to accept the answer, if it has solved your question, activate the "checkbox"!

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

- Node the linework
- Polygonize the set of noded lines (this automatically discards any lines which do not form polygons)
- Compute the area of the polygonal result.

```
WITH lines(geom ) AS (VALUES
 ('LINESTRING (170 250, 80 200, 60 110, 100 70, 145 58, 200 90, 210 150, 165 172, 130 130, 160 90, 200 70, 280 60, 310 70, 360 110, 400 180)'::geometry)
,('LINESTRING (305 6, 260 40, 250 100, 280 160, 344 145, 400 100, 405 78, 375 53)')
,('LINESTRING (540 100, 490 130, 450 90, 459 35, 530 50)')
)
,noded AS (SELECT ST_Node( ST_Collect(geom)) geom FROM lines)
SELECT ST_Area( ST_Polygonize( geom)) FROM noded;
```

**Update:** If some of lines are coincident (have shared linework), then `ST_Union` should be used instead of `ST_Node ( ST_Collect`.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

So,
Since you decided to make the task more complicated by combining 2 situations into one here is my solution for your specific situation as shown in your picture.

The source geodata is a table with the name "line" EPSG:4326.

Pre-create line identifiers 1,2,3 - they will help us to select/dispose of the necessary/unless lines...

Run the script as CTE:

```
WITH
    tbla AS (SELECT id, (ST_Dump(geom)).geom geom FROM line),
    tblb AS (SELECT a.id, (ST_Dump(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom))).geom geom FROM tbla a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) AND a.id<b.id),
    tblc AS (SELECT ST_Union(ST_Buffer(geom, 0.0001, 'side=right')) geom FROM tblb),
    tbld AS (SELECT DISTINCT (ST_Dump(ST_Split(a.geom, b.geom))).geom geom FROM tblc a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
    tble AS (SELECT DISTINCT ST_MakePolygon(ST_InteriorRingN(geom,1)) geom FROM tbld),
    tblf AS (SELECT a.id, (ST_Dump(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom))).geom geom FROM tbla a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) AND a.id>b.id),
    tblg AS (SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 0.0001, 'side=left') geom FROM tblf UNION SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 0.0001, 'side=right') geom FROM tblb),
    tblh AS (SELECT ST_Union(geom) geom FROM tblg),
    tbli AS (SELECT DISTINCT (ST_Dump(ST_Split(a.geom, b.geom))).geom geom FROM tblh a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
    tblj AS (SELECT DISTINCT ST_MakePolygon(ST_InteriorRingN(geom,1)) geom FROM tbli)
    SELECT ST_Union(geom) geom FROM (SELECT * FROM tble UNION SELECT * FROM tblj) foo
```

Check your result,

Good luck in knowing...